# No query string was present- GraphQL Javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql

Im doing following query in javscript and GraphQL:

```
const query2 = `
    query{
        ethereum(network: bsc) {
          address(address: {is: "ETHEREUMADDRESSGOSHERE"}) {
            balances {
              currency {
                symbol
                address
              }
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
      `;


const url = "https://graphql.bitquery.io/";
const opts = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "X-API-KEY": "APIKEYGOESHERE"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        query2
    })
};


fetch(url, opts)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

when I run this i get a "No query string was present" error in my console.

I have this query from this site:
https://graphql.bitquery.io/ide

and Im using the "All token of a BSC Address" query, in case you want to replicate it.

What is going wrong here?
I ran a similliar query before and it worked just fine.
I was also googling this error, prior to posting that message and all i found in regards to it was the same error in python, but in my case im using javscript so i cnat really use those answers.

Comment: Why `JSON.stringify` a string?

Comment: because i used it in a different query and it did work. What can i use instead of stringify

Comment: i tried parse but it desnt work, some unexpected token error is what i get

Comment: use search??  check (commpare with working) network requests???  ... earlier was `query`, not `query2`? ...  `{ query2 }` is a shortcut to `{ query2: query2 }` ... then rename to `query` or use `{ query: query2 }`

Comment: perfect fren, this did work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rename the query variable query2. Replace both instances of "query2" with "query" and it will work.